# Why do I get an undefined reference although everything seems alright ? (C++ Mingw)

Tags: c++, g++, linker-errors, portable-executable

My problem is fairly trivial and simple, I am trying to write a packer and to do so I need to parse PE files, so I'm trying to use the [C++ pe-parse library](https://github.com/trailofbits/pe-parse).

I built it following the instructions and I'm now trying to link it to my simple `main.cpp` file:

```
#include <pe-parse/parse.h>

int main(int ac, char **av)
{
    peparse::parsed_pe *p = peparse::ParsePEFromFile(av[0]);
    return 0;
}
```

Here is my file structure:

```
.
├── src
│      main.cpp
├── lib
│      pe-parse.lib
├── bin
│      pe-parse.dll
└── include
    └ pe-parse
         nt-headers.h
         parse.h
         to_string.h
```

MinGW is indeed x64 (`x86_64-w64-mingw32`) and my libraries also (`pei-x86-64` for both `pe-parse.dll` and `pe-parse.lib`)

When I run

```
g++ -Wall -Wextra .\src\main.cpp -I.\include\ -L.\bin\ -lpe-parse
```

from root, I get the following linking error:

```
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe:
C:\Users\gz\AppData\Local\Temp\ccxml3rK.o:packer.cpp:(.text+0x1f): undefined reference to `peparse::ParsePEFromFile(char const*)'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

When I run `nm` on `pe-parse.lib` I am able to find the symbol. `pe-parse.dll` does not contain any, and I tried to to replace `-L.\bin\` with  `-L.\lib\`

Any ideas ? I believe the `.lib` is an import library that has to be linked with the `.dll`, but I can't find a way to.

Thank you.

Comment: What if you add `-L.\lib\ `?

Comment: @Quimby same problem with this command:
`g++ -Wall -Wextra .\src\packer.cpp -I.\include\ -L.\bin\ -L.\lib\ -lpe-parse`

Comment: Ah, I did not see the edit, can you look into the dll/lib to see whether the symbol is really there and is exported?

Comment: Here is the result of `nm .\lib\pe-parse.lib`:

```pe-parse.dll:
0000000000000000 I .idata$4
0000000000000000 I .idata$5
0000000000000000 I .idata$6
0000000000000000 T .text
0000000000000000 T ?ParsePEFromFile@peparse@@YAPEAU_parsed_pe@1@PEBD@Z
0000000000000000 I __imp_?ParsePEFromFile@peparse@@YAPEAU_parsed_pe@1@PEBD@Z
                 U __IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR_pe-parse```

From my understanding, it is here.
Thank you for your help

Comment: Do *not* use `-L.\bin` or try to link with DLLs. Only link with `.lib` files.

Comment: Hmm, I did try your example with latest version from GitHub and indeed it does export the lib and your `main.cpp` + cmd works for me. But I am on Linux without access to MinGW, so sorry I cannot reproduce it :(

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. This is what I tried at first, it outputs the same error. I tried linking the .dll out of despair

Comment: @Quimby Thanks for trying, at least I know the problem is related with my windows environment

Comment: What error message do you get when you specify an empty directory with `-L`? Does it give you the same one? Or does it give you a more obvious "failed to link library" message? I ask because on Linux, g++ expects libraries specified via `-l` to have a `lib` prefix, which yours does not. In my environment, it would fail to even find the library.

Comment: @AlexanderGuyer from the [ld documentation](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/WIN32.html), under *direct linking to dll* you can see that `.lib` does not necessarily need a lib prefix to be recognized, I think it is needed only for `.a` libraries.
If I compile with `g++ [...] -L -lpe-parse`, the error remains the same, however the library can't be found with `-L.` or without any `-L`

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. Tried `g++ [...] "C:\...\lib\" -lpe-parse`, got `cannot find C:\...\lib" -lpe-parse: Invalid argument`. I think I failed the syntax

Comment: I didn't ask you to use backslashes or "-l", but nevermind. You have a MSVC-compiled library. You cannot use it with mingw or any other gcc-derived compiler.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. Thank you for this ! I will try to see if lib2a helps resolving the issue.

Comment: No it will not. Cannot means cannot. You either recompile pe-parse with gcc, or recompile your code with msvc.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. Exactly, works, thanks again. Can you post an answer so that I mark as solved ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a library produced by MSVC and you are trying to use g++ to link with it.

Microsoft C++ compiler is not compatible with g++. Objects produced by one of them cannot use objects compiled by the other. They use vastly different ABIs and different standard library implementations.

Your only option is to recompile everything with one compiler.